# How can I create my own private server for a game like LoL?

Tags: league-of-legends

I want to run some build tests without going through the process of leveling for 30 minutes a game by running a private server where I can control the variables.  Does anyone know how I can create do this on my computer?

Comment: Sometimes going through the 30 minutes is exactly what a build needs to be tested. The buildup of the build in respect to the game and how it sustains throughout the game is almost as important as its final effectiveness.

Answer (score 10):

The closest you'll be able to get to this is to create a custom game in the client where your teammates and the other team are all bots (or it's just you by yourself). You can't host your own LoL server as all legitimate LoL servers are owned by Riot.

To create a custom game on the Riot servers:

1. Click the big red Play button.
2. Click "custom" in the list of options on the left.
3. Click "Join/Create"
4. Click on the "Create Game" button in the lower right.
5. Configure the game settings, then click "Create Game".
6. If you want bots on either side, click the "Add Bot" buttons.
7. Click "Start Game".

If you play a custom, you can end it at any time without incurring a "leave" penalty.

Comment: You can create custom Dominion games now too, which will get you faster money for testing items.

Comment: Yea but this does not solve the problem of leveling for 30 minutes...

Comment: I strongly disagree because a step is missing. Reverse-engineering their code would be a more logical first step.  By sweeping values, you will be able to tune your physics engine. You can also definitely get skin and model files from any modern game (LOL would be very easy to do). Be careful not to abuse reverse engineering for hacking or unlicensed usage. -<3 try contributing a level maker if you go there, bro: I'd love to help. +1 if you would, too.

Answer (score 0):

After doing some digging and looking i have found the Github of someone called rolle3k. And it seems he has written an emulator for lol, now i don't know if this works... or if this is the new version. But it never hurts checking it out right?

https://github.com/rolle3k

Other then that, you could do what Shaun told you... but you are then stuck again with playing 30 min and such...

Comment: Custom games have no leave penalty. You can leave whenever you want. :)

Comment: @Shaun Never said anything about the penalty, i did say that in the end it is gonna take you 30 min to get a full build vs custom bots, and in the end it is worth nothing, cause the bots are to easy to test the build on.

Comment: I was addressing the comment that you're "stuck" playing bots for 30 minutes. You're not really stuck because you can leave whenever you want.